# このコードのsqrtの部分でCannot resolve methodと出るのですがどうすればいいのでしょうか

Tags: java

はじめてスタックオーバーフローを使いますよろしくお願いします。

```
private boolean isPrime(BigInteger num) {
        if (num.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2)) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(2); i.compareTo(num.sqrt()) <= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            if (num.mod(i).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger.sqrt()`はJava9からサポートされています。

> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#sqrt()
>
> (sinceの箇所を参照)

利用しているJDKのバージョンを9以上にするとよいと思います。

Comment: 直りました！ありがとうございます。